# ansible.legacy.setup fails with return code 0 and no messages in new Molecule role

Tags: ansible, molecule

I'm trying to run `molecule converge` on a newly-created Molecule role (created by running `molecule init role shahradr.srx_config --driver-name docker`), but I'm getting the following error when running the converge step:

```
fatal: [instance]: FAILED! => {
    "ansible_facts": {},
    "changed": false,
    "failed_modules": {
        "ansible.legacy.setup": {
            "ansible_facts": {
                "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3"
            },
            "failed": true,
            "module_stderr": "",
            "module_stdout": "",
            "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
            "rc": 0
        }
    },
    "msg": "The following modules failed to execute: ansible.legacy.setup\n"
}
```

I've tried different container images, but they all give me the same error. The ansible.legacy.setup task *seems* to be the culprit, judging from the value in `msg`, but it looks like it was able to find the Python interpreter, the return code is 0, and there are no errors in stderr/stdout. I'm wondering if anyone has ever seen anything similar before?

Here are some of the relevant files—let me know what you all think!

**molecule.yml**

```yaml
---
dependency:
  name: galaxy
driver:
  name: docker
platforms:
  - name: instance
    image: python # also tried quay.io/quay/ubuntu and quay.io/centos/centos:stream8, but no dice

provisioner:
  name: ansible
  env:
    ANSIBLE_VERBOSITY: 4

verifier:
  name: ansible
```

**converge.yml**

```yaml
---
- name: Converge
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: "Include shahradr.srx_config"
      include_role:
        name: "shahradr.srx_config"
```

**`molecule converge` output**

```
PLAYBOOK: converge.yml *********************************************************
Positional arguments: /workspaces/playbook-srx/molecule/default/converge.yml
verbosity: 4
connection: smart
timeout: 10
become_method: sudo
tags: ('all',)
skip_tags: ('notest', 'molecule-notest')
inventory: ('/home/vscode/.cache/molecule/playbook-srx/default/inventory',)
forks: 50
1 plays in /workspaces/playbook-srx/molecule/default/converge.yml

PLAY [Converge] ****************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
task path: /workspaces/playbook-srx/molecule/default/converge.yml:2
fatal: [instance]: FAILED! => {
    "ansible_facts": {},
    "changed": false,
    "failed_modules": {
        "ansible.legacy.setup": {
            "ansible_facts": {
                "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3"
            },
            "failed": true,
            "module_stderr": "",
            "module_stdout": "",
            "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
            "rc": 0
        }
    },
    "msg": "The following modules failed to execute: ansible.legacy.setup\n"
}
Loading collection community.docker from /home/vscode/.cache/ansible-compat/874d52/collections/ansible_collections/community/docker
<instance> ESTABLISH DOCKER CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<instance> EXEC ['/usr/bin/docker', b'exec', b'-i', 'instance', '/bin/sh', '-c', "/bin/sh -c 'echo ~ && sleep 0'"]
<instance> EXEC ['/usr/bin/docker', b'exec', b'-i', 'instance', '/bin/sh', '-c', '/bin/sh -c \'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /root/.ansible/tmp `"&& mkdir "` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1671693905.9801428-31004-54819707870645 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1671693905.9801428-31004-54819707870645="` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1671693905.9801428-31004-54819707870645 `" ) && sleep 0\'']
<instance> Attempting python interpreter discovery
<instance> EXEC ['/usr/bin/docker', b'exec', b'-i', 'instance', '/bin/sh', '-c', '/bin/sh -c \'echo PLATFORM; uname; echo FOUND; command -v \'"\'"\'python3.11\'"\'"\'; command -v \'"\'"\'python3.10\'"\'"\'; command -v \'"\'"\'python3.9\'"\'"\'; command -v \'"\'"\'python3.8\'"\'"\'; command -v \'"\'"\'python3.7\'"\'"\'; command -v \'"\'"\'python3.6\'"\'"\'; command -v \'"\'"\'python3.5\'"\'"\'; command -v \'"\'"\'/usr/bin/python3\'"\'"\'; command -v \'"\'"\'/usr/libexec/platform-python\'"\'"\'; command -v \'"\'"\'python2.7\'"\'"\'; command -v \'"\'"\'/usr/bin/python\'"\'"\'; command -v \'"\'"\'python\'"\'"\'; echo ENDFOUND && sleep 0\'']
<instance> EXEC ['/usr/bin/docker', b'exec', b'-i', 'instance', '/bin/sh', '-c', "/bin/sh -c '/usr/local/bin/python3.11 && sleep 0'"]
Using module file /usr/local/python/3.10.9/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ansible/modules/setup.py
<instance> PUT /home/vscode/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-30997q9s35pno/tmpkw2qa3kw TO /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1671693905.9801428-31004-54819707870645/AnsiballZ_setup.py
<instance> EXEC ['/usr/bin/docker', b'exec', b'-i', 'instance', '/bin/sh', '-c', "/bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1671693905.9801428-31004-54819707870645/ /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1671693905.9801428-31004-54819707870645/AnsiballZ_setup.py && sleep 0'"]
<instance> EXEC ['/usr/bin/docker', b'exec', b'-i', 'instance', '/bin/sh', '-c', "/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python3 /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1671693905.9801428-31004-54819707870645/AnsiballZ_setup.py && sleep 0'"]
<instance> EXEC ['/usr/bin/docker', b'exec', b'-i', 'instance', '/bin/sh', '-c', "/bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1671693905.9801428-31004-54819707870645/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'"]

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
instance                   : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

**`ansible --version` output**

```
ansible [core 2.14.1]
  config file = None
  configured module search path = ['/home/vscode/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/python/3.10.9/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /home/vscode/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /usr/local/python/current/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.10.9 (main, Dec 18 2022, 21:59:57) [GCC 10.2.1 20210110] (/usr/local/python/3.10.9/bin/python3.10)
  jinja version = 3.1.2
  libyaml = True
```

**`molecule --version` output**

```
molecule 4.0.4 using python 3.10 
    ansible:2.14.1
    delegated:4.0.4 from molecule
    docker:2.1.0 from molecule_docker requiring collections: community.docker>=3.0.2 ansible.posix>=1.4.0
```

### Running with an older version of Ansible

**`ansible --version` output**

```
ansible [core 2.12.0]
  config file = None
  configured module search path = ['/home/vscode/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/python/3.8.16/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /home/vscode/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /usr/local/python/current/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.8.16 (default, Dec 22 2022, 09:25:11) [GCC 10.2.1 20210110]
  jinja version = 3.1.2
  libyaml = True
```

**`molecule --version` output**

```
molecule 4.0.4 using python 3.8 
    ansible:2.12.0
    delegated:4.0.4 from molecule
    docker:2.1.0 from molecule_docker requiring collections: community.docker>=3.0.2 ansible.posix>=1.4.0
```

**`molecule converge` output**

```
PLAY [Converge] ****************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
task path: /workspaces/playbook-srx/molecule/default/converge.yml:2
Loading collection community.docker from /home/vscode/.cache/ansible-compat/874d52/collections/ansible_collections/community/docker
<instance> ESTABLISH DOCKER CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<instance> EXEC ['/usr/bin/docker', b'exec', b'-i', 'instance', '/bin/sh', '-c', "/bin/sh -c 'echo ~ && sleep 0'"]
<instance> EXEC ['/usr/bin/docker', b'exec', b'-i', 'instance', '/bin/sh', '-c', '/bin/sh -c \'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /root/.ansible/tmp `"&& mkdir "` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1671797674.6429565-10250-103016948866633 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1671797674.6429565-10250-103016948866633="` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1671797674.6429565-10250-103016948866633 `" ) && sleep 0\'']
<instance> Attempting python interpreter discovery
<instance> EXEC ['/usr/bin/docker', b'exec', b'-i', 'instance', '/bin/sh', '-c', '/bin/sh -c \'echo PLATFORM; uname; echo FOUND; command -v \'"\'"\'python3.10\'"\'"\'; command -v \'"\'"\'python3.9\'"\'"\'; command -v \'"\'"\'python3.8\'"\'"\'; command -v \'"\'"\'python3.7\'"\'"\'; command -v \'"\'"\'python3.6\'"\'"\'; command -v \'"\'"\'python3.5\'"\'"\'; command -v \'"\'"\'/usr/bin/python3\'"\'"\'; command -v \'"\'"\'/usr/libexec/platform-python\'"\'"\'; command -v \'"\'"\'python2.7\'"\'"\'; command -v \'"\'"\'python2.6\'"\'"\'; command -v \'"\'"\'/usr/bin/python\'"\'"\'; command -v \'"\'"\'python\'"\'"\'; echo ENDFOUND && sleep 0\'']
<instance> EXEC ['/usr/bin/docker', b'exec', b'-i', 'instance', '/bin/sh', '-c', "/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python3 && sleep 0'"]
Using module file /usr/local/python/3.8.16/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ansible/modules/setup.py
<instance> PUT /home/vscode/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-10226yeg_lu0l/tmpg3_giq0y TO /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1671797674.6429565-10250-103016948866633/AnsiballZ_setup.py
<instance> EXEC ['/usr/bin/docker', b'exec', b'-i', 'instance', '/bin/sh', '-c', "/bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1671797674.6429565-10250-103016948866633/ /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1671797674.6429565-10250-103016948866633/AnsiballZ_setup.py && sleep 0'"]
<instance> EXEC ['/usr/bin/docker', b'exec', b'-i', 'instance', '/bin/sh', '-c', "/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1671797674.6429565-10250-103016948866633/AnsiballZ_setup.py && sleep 0'"]
<instance> EXEC ['/usr/bin/docker', b'exec', b'-i', 'instance', '/bin/sh', '-c', "/bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1671797674.6429565-10250-103016948866633/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'"]
fatal: [instance]: FAILED! => {
    "ansible_facts": {},
    "changed": false,
    "failed_modules": {
        "ansible.legacy.setup": {
            "ansible_facts": {
                "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
            },
            "failed": true,
            "module_stderr": "",
            "module_stdout": "",
            "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
            "rc": 0
        }
    },
    "msg": "The following modules failed to execute: ansible.legacy.setup\n"
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `ansible --version` and `molecule --version`

Comment: For sure—I just updated the post now!

Comment: It could be that your Ansible version is too new for Molecule. Would it be possible to downgrade Ansible?

Comment: [I can't reproduce your issue](https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/f657b81019f7efe9a42b60644b0fe4af). I also tested with a non pre-built image and get the same result (i.e. facts are gathered correctly).

Comment: @KevinC that was a good idea, but unfortunately it gives the same results. I've updated the question with the `--version` and `molecule converge` outputs.

Comment: @Zeitounator thank you so much for trying that out! At least now we can rule out configuration issues, and it probably points to something weird with my setup. I am running this in a development container—I'm wondering now if that could be the culprit? I'll play with my setup a bit, see if it works outside the devcontainer, maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I might have figured it out—it looks like the issue was caused by my [devcontainer](https://containers.dev/) configuration. I had enabled both the [docker-in-docker](https://github.com/devcontainers/features/tree/dbf069a5db328e0413300094a0dc37f520000375/src/docker-in-docker) and [docker-from-docker](https://github.com/devcontainers/features/tree/dbf069a5db328e0413300094a0dc37f520000375/src/docker-from-docker) features at the same time, which resulted in the issue listed above.

If I disable either feature, then the `molecule converge` command completes successfully, and I don't get the `ansible.legacy.setup` error detailed in this question.

#### `.devcontainer/devcontainer.json`

```json
{
  "name": "Debian",
  "runArgs": ["--init"],
  "build": {
    "dockerfile": "Dockerfile",
    "args": { "VARIANT": "bullseye" }
  },
  "settings": {},
  "extensions": [],
  "remoteUser": "vscode",
  "features": {
    // Having both the docker-in-docker and docker-from-docker features enabled
    // causes the ansible.legacy.setup error detailed in this question.
    "ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/docker-in-docker:1": {
      "version": "latest"
    },
    "ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/docker-from-docker:1": {
      "version": "latest"
    },
    "ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/node:1": {
      "version": "16"
    },
    "ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/python:1": {
      "version": "3.8"
    }
  },
  "postCreateCommand": ["./.devcontainer/post-create.sh"]
}
```

#### `molecule converge` output with both the docker-in-docker and docker-from-docker features enabled

```
TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
fatal: [instance]: FAILED! => {
    "ansible_facts": {},
    "changed": false,
    "failed_modules": {
        "ansible.legacy.setup": {
            "ansible_facts": {
                "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
            },
            "failed": true,
            "module_stderr": "",
            "module_stdout": "",
            "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
            "rc": 0
        }
    },
    "msg": "The following modules failed to execute: ansible.legacy.setup\n"
}
```

#### `molecule converge` output with only the docker-in-docker feature enabled

```
TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
ok: [instance]
```

#### `molecule converge` output with only the docker-from-docker feature enabled

```
TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
ok: [instance]
```